# How to open new screens in new JavaFx stages in Angela Caicedo's framework on Managing Multiple Screens in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using Angela Caicedo's framework to Managing Multiple Screens in my JavaFX application. The problem is that I'd like to have some ***screens open up in new stages***, or ***pop-ups to open up as pop-ups*** and not new screens. Could anyone please have a hint on how to go about this using Angela Caicedo's framework.

**Here are her tutorials:**

Managing Multiple Screens in JavaFX. [Part I](https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1)

Managing Multiple Screens in JavaFX. [Part II](https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx)

Video -> [Managing Multiple Screens in JavaFX: here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GsdaZWDcdY)

Thank you all in advance.

**EDIT:**

*If anyone could help with a possible way on how the individual separate screens could be resized, that would be a huge bonus.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use my own MDI-framework. For dialogs I use internal windows from [jfxtras](http://jfxtras.org) library (Now, I start work on highly customizable InternalWindow). You can see sample on my  [javafx-MultipleScreens-framework](https://github.com/zella/javafx-MultipleScreens-framework) github.

Comment: [@DarkDarker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1996639/darkdarker) I never knew of this project. Thanks for the intro man!

Comment: You are welcome! I update my sample with passing parameters between controllers

Comment: Hey [@DarkDarker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1996639/darkdarker). You referred me to [JFXtras](http://jfxtras.org/) some time back. I'm trying to use JFXtras Agenda but I'm stuck implementing it. Could you please help guide me. I have this question [here: How to list dates from database onto JFXtras Agenda as Appointments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660846/how-to-list-dates-from-database-onto-jfxtras-agenda-as-appointments-google-cale) but I haven't had any response yet. Hope you can help.