# How to list dates from database onto JFXtras Agenda as Appointments: Google Calender style event listing

Tags: java, calendar, javafx, jfxtras

I have ***event dates, titles, venues, attendees, start & end times, location and other metadata*** collected from users via forms then stored in a mysql database table. I would like to retrieve the events from the database and list them in *Google Calender style*. So far I only know of **JFXtras Agenda** having this kind of implementation.

I've been trying for a long time now to work with JFXtras Agenda but I'm stuck at retrieving the events from the database and listing them on the Agenda as Appointments.

How do I go about it? I'm ready to try out any other implementation that lists events from data base like Google Calender does.

Thank you in advance.

**Ps.**

I think my problem is that I don't understand what an appointment group is from ***AppointmentGroup Interface (Class Agenda.AppointmentImpl)*** is *supposed to do/ what it is....*

From the API: *".......An appointment group is a binding element between appointments; it contains information about visualization....."*

What does *"binding element between appointments"* mean?

Comment: Did you see https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-ensemble/blob/master/src/ensemble/samples/controls/AgendaSample1.java ?

Comment: Yes I did. I was looking for an implementation that does it by getting items from a database. But the part I'm really not getting is .... **From the API** - ***Interface Agenda.AppointmentGroup***: *"....An appointment group is a binding element between appointments; it contains information about visualization...."* What is an **appointment group**, what does it do? Thank you

Comment: How i see from sample Appointments with same AppointmentGroup have same color. It's just visual grouping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create custom model

```
public class Event {

    GregorianCalendar startTime;
    GregorianCalendar endTime;
    ...

    public GregorianCalendar getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(GregorianCalendar startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public GregorianCalendar getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(GregorianCalendar endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }
    ...
}
```

2) Retrive events from database to `List<Event> myEvents`

3) Fill your Agenda

```
Agenda lAgenda = new Agenda();
...
for (Event e : myEvents) {
    lAgenda.appointments().add(
        new Agenda.AppointmentImpl()
        .withStartTime(e.getStartTime())
        .withEndTime(e.getEndTime()));
        ...
}
```

Comment: You don't know just how much you helped, [DarkDarker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1996639/darkdarker). If I could accept your answer and Up-Vote you 30 times, I could. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: One last thing please. Could you know how I can add an action Listener so that when an appointment on an agenda is clicked a new window with more details on that particular clicked appointment opens?

Comment: I just added a question on the comment above **[Here:** ***How can I add an action Listener onto an appointment in an agenda (JFXtras Agenda)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681781/how-can-i-add-an-action-listener-onto-an-appointment-in-an-agenda-jfxtras-agend)***. Please take a look if you can. Thanks for the help...

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction; I was not monitoring stackoverflow for issues.

Is this still an issue? If so, please file an issue on github.